# Is there a C++Builder component that mix a Listbox and a treeview?

Tags: delphi, treeview, c++builder, uicomponents

I need to display some hierarchical data with columns.
So A kind of **listbox** mixed with a **treeview**.

I've look at the standard components and JCL/JVCL, but nothing similar. Any idea ?

**EDIT**

I'm using RADStudio XE, so the component should be up-to-date !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd go with [VirtualTreeview](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=38). Excellent component!

Comment: Virtual treeview makes a great grid+tree combo, and while written in Delphi, works great in C++Builder apps too. VirtualTreeView is used by lots of developers, and it is even used by the RAD Studio IDE itself. (You have to go download the source code though! It's not on the component palette)

Comment: @Warren P. Where is it use by the RAD Studio IDE ?

Comment: @TridentT - see screenshot of usage in the Delphi IDE here: http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=15&Itemid=33

Comment: @Chris: ok, it seems to be everywhere :)